# How can I get back button working when searchview in Android

Tags: android, searchview

I've been searching for more than 4 hours all over the internet how to get the back button working properly when searchview is opened but I just can't achieve it.

Here is my searchview.

```
    searchview  = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchview.setOnClickListener(this);
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.searchView){

           //Cursor cursor = manager.obtenerIDColumnaServicio(searchview.getQuery().toString());
            adapterOfDataBase.changeCursor(cursor);
        }
    }
```

Here is the xml:

```
   <SearchView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="63dp"
                    android:id="@+id/searchView"
                    android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
                    android:backgroundTint="#ff000000"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />
```

All this withing a huge class using SQL and some methods to insert, delete, etc etc tables & entries.
So **my problem is** that everytime I click on the searchview it expands in order to write the text, everyting ok, but when I push back button from android nothing happens.

I tried 2 options but none worked, if you could just help me....

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { //MEJORAR ESTO
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        searchview.onActionViewCollapsed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
//None of this 2 methods are working. I tried them separately
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (!this.searchview.isIconified()) {
        this.searchview.setIconified(true);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is correct approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48989340/4026686

Answer (score 11):

When searchView is open and back button is pressed you expect to see the searchView closed (aka setIconified(true)) This is a standar behaviour as per google apps searchview implementation.

So all you need to do is something like that

```
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                mSearchView.setIconified(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: this cause problems if have another editable control in the activity (ie EditText), then the SearchView cannot get the focus correctly anymore.

Comment: adding a setQuery("", false); before setIconified work for me. So my code look like : if (!hasFocus)   {
    setQuery("", false);
    setIconified(true);
   }

Answer (score 4):

In my case just adding :

```
setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

to the SearchView works as a work around for this issue,

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 2):

Try to use OnActionExpandListener on MenuItem

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = null;
        if (searchItem != null) {
            searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        }
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(MainActivity.this.getComponentName()));
        }
        searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO do your stuff when back button is pressed
            return true;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

In case of you use AppCompatSupportv7

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                // TODO do your stuff when back button is pressed
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Although first option does not work anymore , second option works clearly .

Answer (score 0):

instead of this.searchview.setIconified(true) try this if you are using support library:

```
searchview.onActionViewCollapsed();
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

or this if you are not using support library:

```
searchview.onActionViewCollapsed();
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting at **Android 9**, Google fixes this problem by themselves.