# MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener deprecated

Tags: android, searchview, deprecated

I have some code that sets a boolean if the search view is open or not.

```
MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(action_search, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item){
                isSearch = true;
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item){
                isSearch = false;
                return true;
            }
        });
```

It works.  I'm happy with the way it responds.  However, it it shows as deprecated, the setOnActionExpandListener is crossed out with the warning

> android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener is deprecated

Suggestions?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> `android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener` is deprecated

Yes **`MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener`** This method was deprecated in API level 26.1.0.

> Suggestions?

Use [**`MenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#setOnActionExpandListener(android.view.MenuItem,%20android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener)) directly.

- **`MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener`** on this menu item to be notified when the associated action `view` is expanded or collapsed. The `menu item` must be configured to expand or collapse its action `view` using the flag `SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW`.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_order);
item.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
     @Override
      public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
          isSearch = true;
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
           isSearch = false;
           return true;
      }
});
```

Comment: it only works if searchview is always expanded (marked as `collapseActionView `)

Comment: @AshwinH happy to hear that feel free to upvote my answer

Answer (score 11):

This interface was deprecated in API level 26.1.0.

Instead of `MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener`

Use `MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener` directly.

[Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html)

**Sample:**

```
  MenuItem menuItemSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

     menuItemSearch.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
            isSearch = true;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
            isSearch = false;
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**Bonus**

setting `OnQueryTextListener` and `OnCloseListener`

```
    MenuItem menuItemSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

  final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItemSearch.getActionView();

     searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

          //Do something

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {

        // do something
            return false;
        }
    });
```